# Why does IF statement fail?

Tags: if-statement, boolean-expression, micropython

I have a horrible feeling that the answer to this question is going to be obvious, but...

I am reading data from a small file in MicroPython.  The value of the line I read determines whether a bool variable, **debug** is set or not.  I have tried this two ways:

```
        s = f.readline()
        print("s = ",s)
        if s == "1":
            debug = True
        else:
            debug = False
        print("debug = ",debug)
```

and

```
        s = f.readline()
        print("s = ",s)
        debug = True if s == "1" else False
        print("debug = ",debug)
```

In both cases, the printed output is:

```
s =  1
debug =  False
```

I have also tried removing the quotes from around the 1 in case it's reading this as an integer rather than a string, but the result is the same.  This is silly!  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a "\n" on the end of s perhaps, so s == "1\n"?

Comment: Thank you, Mike!  I knew it would be something simple - just need to put a [:1] on the end of the readline statement and everything works fine.

Comment: @PhilTilson Pleased to of helped.  If you feel I answered the original question could you please mark it as the Answer?  Thankyou very much, Mike.